# If $x$, $\{x\}$, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ are in G.P, find $x$.

Tags: quadratics, ceiling-and-floor-functions, geometric-progressions, fractional-part

> If $x$, $\{x\}$, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ are in Geometric Progression, find $x$; $x \neq 0$.
>
> Here, $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$

Some properties are pretty evident:
$$0\leq \{x\} < 1 \tag{1}$$
$$\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x\tag{2}$$

But I can't seem to be able to use them to substitute and find an equation for $x$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is GP? This is not  a standard abbreviation.

Comment: A trivial example is $x=0$

Comment: @avid19 Good catch... I forgot to mention $x \neq 0$. :-)

Comment: @avid19: I thought of that, but considered $0/0$ to be undefined and therefore $0, 0, 0$ are not really in geometric progression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic Approach.** We assume that $x > 1$.  (This is a mistake; Michael's answer gives a solution where $x < 0$.)

In this case, let the three numbers be denoted, instead, $r, n, n+r$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $r$ is a real value such that $0 \leq r < 1$.  We can quickly determine that $r > 1/2$ (why?) and so $n = 1$ (why?).  Then find $r$ such that

$$
r = \frac{1}{1+r}
$$

You should obtain a reasonably familiar number (for $1+r$).

Comment: The golden ratio: $\phi$. That's really awesome.

Comment: @ambigram_maker: It is related to the fact that the geometric series $1, \phi, \phi^2, \phi^3$ is also additive.  It is, in a way, the additive series that all other additive series (that obey the recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 2$) "strive toward", in the sense that the other additive series have $a_n/a_{n-1} \to \phi$ in the limit.

Comment: Like the Fibonacci Series (the first example I could think of). Yes, I see. I even used Fibonacci numbers to approximate $\phi$.

Comment: @ambigram_maker: I mistakenly assumed that $x > 1$.  Michael's answer gives a solution where $x < 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=n+y$, $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $y=\{x\}$  Since these numbers are in geometric progression, we have $x/y=y/n$, or

$$\frac {n+y}{y}=\frac yn$$
$$(n+y)n=y^2$$
$$y^2 - n^2 - ny = 0$$
$$y=\frac{n\pm n\sqrt{5}}2$$

$y$ is between 0 and 1, so $n(1\pm\sqrt{5})/2$ has to be between $0$ and $1$.
This is impossible for $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ as the first positive multiple of 1.618 is more than 1. But for $(1-\sqrt{5})/2\approx-0.618$, we have have $n=-1$

So 
$$n=-1\\y=n\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}2$$
$$x=n+y=\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}2
$$

So $x=-\phi^{-2}$ and $\{x\}=\phi^{-1}$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck but at least it is correct; Brian Tung has put $\lfloor x\rfloor$ as the middle number.

Comment: @Michael: But if $x = \phi$, then $\{x\} = \phi-1, \lfloor x \rfloor = 1, x = \phi$ are in geometric progression and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ *is* the middle number.  Your solution is valid also, and I will amend my answer to so indicate.

Comment: Oh, my mistake.